# Webpack externals Module not found

Tags: typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6

Hello hope you are well.

I am currently struggling with webpack a bit and was looking for the best solution to cater for the following :

I want to load config from json from my single page app and use it wherever. This actually works well :

```
externals: {
    'config': JSON.stringify(getAppConfig())
}
```

This is of course added into webpack config and getAppConfig is:

```
var getAppConfig = () => {
    var finalConfig = require('./config.json');
    if (process.argv.indexOf('--env.production')) {
        finalConfig = Object.assign(finalConfig, require('./config.production.json'));
    }
    /*more stuff here but removed for simplicity*/
    return finalConfig;
}
```

Then inside a module, I do

```
import Config from 'config';
```

And use the imported javascript object. Surprisingly everything works as expected :) My problem actually is this ugly error in webpack

```
ERROR in ./ClientApp/store/WeatherForecasts.ts 
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'config' in
```

I really don't want to have fake errors for CI purposes and what not, but I would much rather understand what's going on than just ignore it somehow. Btw, I am using typescript for the project, not sure if it changes anything but best to state all the facts I guess. This is the typescript module definition :

```
declare module 'config' {
    export interface Config {
        backendUrl: string;
    }
    export default {} as Config;
}
```

All help much appreciated.
Peter

Comment: what is the value for `libraryTarget` in your config?

Comment: You might be onto something. I actually have 2 configs, one for server side prerendering, one for client side. Client side, nothing is set and it doesn't complain. Server side it's set to commonjs and it complains. Will look into changing it

Comment: Hmm, ok so changing it to anything doesn't help. But it definitely builds client and not the server version. I'll look into it more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have a solution. And it's I am afraid partially me just not reading docs properly. See I use webpack-merge and I didn't know it can't merge arrays properly. Therefore my server prerendering bundle config overwritten the shared one and it was missing. All good now

Answer (score 0):

I ever had tried to import the global variables(defined in webpack externals configuration) in typescript files. I fixed it by following steps.

1. delete the externals

   externals: {
       lodash: '_',
   },
2. add the lodash to the index.html

```html
<script src="https://images.cloudhubpanel.com/docs/js-lib/lodash-4.17.5.min.js"></script>
```

3. add a **index.d.ts** to the project root folder

```js
declare let _: any; 
export default _;
```

4. reference the **_** don't need to import ,like this, it is one of my files

```js
import Enums from './EnumsManager';
import { getStore } from './localStorage';
/**
 * getAuthorization
 */
export const getAuthorization = (): string => {
  const loginUser: any = getStore(Enums.LocalStorageKey);
  if (_.isEmpty(loginUser)) {
    return '';
  }
  const userData: any = JSON.parse(loginUser).token_info;
  if (_.isEmpty(userData)) {
    return '';
  }
  const { token_type, access_token } = userData;
  return `${token_type} ${access_token}`;
};
```

I am trying to use webpack+typescript+react.My project is created by the

```
npm install -g create-react-app

create-react-app my-app --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts
```